# JUnit тесты для DataService

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Как можно это все проверить? Мои мысли:

1. Внести фейковые данные в базу данных.
2. Добавить данные через тест.
3. Задать значения для проверки.
4. Сравнить данные для проверки с данными из БД?

Как это примерно реализовать? Просто с дата сервисами не работал особо вот и возникло затруднение.

```
public class NewsDataService {
    private News news;
    private List<News> newss;
    private DatabaseConnector db;
    private ResultSet result;

    public NewsDataService() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        db = new DatabaseConnector();
        newss = new ArrayList<News>();

    }

    public News getNews(int id) throws SQLException {
        result = db.query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE idnews = " + id);
        result = db.query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE idstudent = " + id);
        result = db.query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE idgroup = " + id);
        while (result.next()) {
            news.setDate(result.getString("date"));
            news.setTitle(result.getString("title"));
            news.setContent(result.getString("content"));
        }
        return news;

    }

    public News findByTitleNews(String title) throws SQLException {
        result = db.query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE title ='" + title + "'");
        while (result.next()) {
            news.setTitle(result.getString("title"));
            news.setId(result.getInt("idnews"));
            news.setId(result.getInt("idgroup"));
            news.setId(result.getInt("idstudent"));
            news.setDate(result.getString("date"));
            news.setContent(result.getString("content"));
        }
        return news;

    }

    public List<News> findAllNews() throws SQLException {
        result = db.query("SELECT * FROM news");
        while (result.next()) {
            news.setTitle(result.getString("title"));
            news.setId(result.getInt("idnews"));
            news.setId(result.getInt("idgroup"));
            news.setId(result.getInt("idgroup"));
            news.setDate(result.getString("date"));
            news.setContent(result.getString("content"));

        }

        return newss;

    }

    public void save(News news) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO news('title', 'content', 'date') "
                + "VALUES ('" + news.getTitle() + "', '" + news.getContent()
                + "', '" + news.getDate() + "',?);";

        PreparedStatement pstmt = db.getConnect().prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.execute();
        pstmt.close();
        System.out.println(sql);
        System.out.println("News successful inserted");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Протестировать текущий вариант класса `NewsDataService` - не самая тривиальная задача для решения, попробую объяснить почему.

- В процессе написания данного класса вы решили заинкапсулировать всю логику работы с БД внутри кода, дойдя до крайне низкого уровня - ручного составления `SQL` запросов. И теперь ваш класс служит *крайне узкоспециализированной цели*, поскольку он умеет только лишь создаваться и отвечать на запросы вида *"дай мне сущность с `id`"* и *"сохрани такую-то сущность"*.

> Чтобы улучшить этот аспект кода (`coupling`), я бы порекомендовал бы вам почитать про [**Inversion of Control,**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) [**Dependency Injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) и про [**ORM.**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM)

- Я могу предложить 3 различных подхода к тестированию текущего варианта реализации `NewsDataService`, которые вполне как можно скомбинировать в тех или иных пропорциях

> - Воспользуйтесь `sandbox-based` подходом - возьмите легковесную базу данных, заполните ее реальными значениями и напишите юнит-тесты без моков вообще. Вообще говоря, если бы вы писали такие тесты перед написанием кода *(следуя методологии `TDD`)*, то вам бы сразу открылись многие минусы и неудобства использования написанного класса. *Специально для таких целей можно использовать [**DbUnit,**](http://www.dbunit.org/) позволяющий упростить создание сендбоксовой базы данных и написание `Setup / Teardown` методов.*
>
>   ---
> - Следуя принципам `IoC`, инициализируйте ваш `DatabaseConnector` в другом месте, а в `NewsDataService` прокидывайте его через конструктор. Это, во-первых, снимает с `NewsDataService` ответственность за инициализацию подключения, а во-вторых упрощает тестирование. Вот здесь уже сам по себе `DatabaseConnector` можно подменить `mock`-объектом, который будет эмулировать часть функциональности, например, на любой запрос `SELECT` будет возвращать предопределенную пачку новостей.
> - **Подход не самый лучший,** потому что `mock`-объект должен быть предельно простым *(иначе потребуются тесты на тесты)*, а этот факт сильно сковывает руки при тестировании. То есть, грубо говоря, вы не можете и не должны парсить запрос в вашем `mock'e`, поэтому максимум, что вы можете делать с его помощью - это разделять запросы `SELECT / UPDATE`, возвращая на них какую-нибудь заранее заданную чушь, ну и, например, проверять, что `databaseConnector.query` вообще был вызван.
> - *Общее правило достаточно простое - если код `mock'a` вызывает вопросы о том, правильно ли он работает **для всех случаев**, то это - плохой `mock`.* Иногда, естественно, бывают ситуации, что без сложного `mock'a` не обойтись, но в таком случае нужно писать тесты на этот самый `mock`, что обычно бывает нежелательным.
>
>   ---
> - Выделить генерацию `SQL` запросов в отдельный класс типа `SqlQueryProvider<?>`. В таком случае ваш текущий код начнет меняться примерно в следующую сторону:
>     `... databaseConnector.query(sqlQueryProvider.getQueryToRetrieveById(...));`
> - Такой подход уже позволяет отдельно покрыть тестами генерацию запросов, и, зная, что запросы к генерируются корректно, серьзно сэкономить на реальном тестировании `NewsDataService`. *Опять же, для тестирования `NewsDataService` в таком случае может пригодиться `mock` на `SqlQueryProvider`.*

- Несколько референсов по теме:

> - [**Unit Testing Database Code**](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/12/UnitTestingDatabaseCode.html)
> - [**Testing With DbUnit**](http://www.dallaway.com/acad/dbunit.html)
> - [**How do I unit test jdbc code in java?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/how-do-i-unit-test-jdbc-code-in-java)

- Всегда, кстати, хотелось посмотреть, как авторы советов типа *"возьмите `XYZMock`, да заmock'айте эту обертку над БД и протестите, делов то"* делают это на практике и сделали бы это, достанься им `legacy` код типа `NewsDataService.`

Answer (score 2):

все зависит от поставленной задачи.

если ваша задача проверить работу БД тогда для этого можно воспользоватся одним из уже существующих фреймворков. для субд оракл: ounit, plunit, pluto, utplsql (этот самый мощний)

если вам нужно проверить работу программы ( хотя здесь вы должны уже быть уверены что СУБД работает правильно ). тогда вам следует придерживатся того плана который вы уже наметили.

как реализовать - сначала создаете массив обьектов с тестовыми данными (можно опустить этот пункт но так проще незапутатся в данных). потом используете их для формирования запросов вставки данных в БД. 
и непосредственно во время теста, - выбираете все данные и проверяете только те обьекты которые вы создали во время теста, - сравниваете их с теми которые вы выбрали. они должны быть равны между собой (можно сравнивать по полям. можно для этого перегрузить метод equals внутри этих обьектов)

но начать стоит с того чтоб исправить ошибки в коде:
1) `private List<News> newss` - это должно быть локальной переменной в методе (во всех где используется). 
2) `private ResultSet result;` - это должно быть локальной переменной в методе (во всех где используется)
3) `PreparedStatement pstmt = db.getConnect().prepareStatement(sql);` - вот эту переменную  наоборот имеет смысл вынести за пределы метода и сделать полем. для того чтоб можно было использовать несколько раз. В самом же методе надос делать так:

```
if(null == pstmt)
{
   pstmt = db.getConnect().prepareStatement(sql);
}
```

вот вы в данном коде использовали PreparedStatement но если смотреть на остальной код то стает что вы не разобрались как это работает. Каждый раз когды вы отсылаете какой-то запрос СУБД она его сначала парсит. Эта операция очень важная и дорогостоющая, - потому что парсер у всей СУБД только один. Посему если слать много разных запросов паралельно то ваша СУБД будет работать очень медленно.
Для того чтоб избежать однотипных запросов есть специальные средства для подстановки параметров. в JDBC это PreparedStatement.

пример:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year_made = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1,2002);

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

// очистить установленные параметры можно так (необходимо для работы в цикле):
ps.clearParameters();
```

Comment: В следующем коде можно неплохо наколоться при multi-threading'е:
>`if(null == pstmt)`
>`{`
>`pstmt = db.getConnect().prepareStatement(sql);`
>`}`

Comment: согласен, если появится необходимость эту проблему можно обсудить в отдельном вопросе :)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы проверить работу вашего класса в независимости от БД, стоит воспользоваться такой концепцией как Mock Objects, и заменить в тесте базу на мок. Почитайте об этом более подробно, статей достаточно. Из библиотек могу посоветовать EasyMock.